# Abstract Class Java Why is my program only printing 0.00?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Abstract Class Java Why is my program only printing 0.00?

```
public class TestEmployee
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee[] folks = new Employee[4]; 

        folks[0] = new SalariedEmployee("Suzy",123,520000.00); 
        folks[1] = new WageEmployee("Fred",456,7.50,40);  
        folks[2] = new SalariedEmployee("Harry",234,45000.00);
        folks[3] = new WageEmployee("Rita",345,7.76,38);

        for(int i=0; i<folks.length; i++)  
        {
            System.out.println(folks[i].getName()
            + " earns " + folks[i].getMonthlyPay() + " each month");
        }
    }
}
```

I added the  missing classes needed to make
the program compile and run properly

```
abstract class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private int number;
    public abstract double getMonthlyPay();

    public Employee(String name, int number, double salary)
    {
        setName(name);
        setNumber(number);
        salary = getMonthlyPay();  
    }

    public Employee(String name, int number, double salary, int hours)
    {
        setName(name);
        setNumber(number);
        salary = getMonthlyPay();  
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }

    public String setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        return this.name;
    }

    public int setNumber(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
        return this.number;
    }
}
```

Please provide an explanation or insight as to why my program is only printing zeroes. I think this is where my problem lies

```
class SalariedEmployee extends Employee
{
    private double yearSalary;

    public SalariedEmployee(String name, int number, double salary)
    {
        super(name, number, salary);
        yearSalary = getMonthlyPay();
    }

    public double getMonthlyPay()
    {
        double monthlyPay = yearSalary / 12;
        return monthlyPay;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return(super.getName() + ", " + super.getNumber() + ", " + getMonthlyPay());
    }

}

class WageEmployee extends Employee
{
    private double wage;
    private int hours;

    public WageEmployee(String name, int number, double salary, int hours)
    {
        super(name, number, salary, hours);
    }

    public double getMonthlyPay()
    {
        double monthlyPay = wage * hours * 4;
        return monthlyPay;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return(super.getName() + ", " + super.getNumber() + ", " + getMonthlyPay());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn to use a debugger and with this tool to help you first identify and then solve your bug. As a side note, when posting code to this or to any site for help, you should strive to format it well, so that folks are able to read it. This includes giving your code proper and regular indentation.

Comment: `public WageEmployee(String name, int number, double salary, int hours)` ... I don't see a compatible defined constructor in the parent class `Employee`.

Comment: You set `yearSalary = getMonthlyPay()` and `getMonthlyPay()` is defined as `monthlyPay = yearSalary / 12`. So the year salary depends on the monthly pay which depends on the year salary? That already doesn't really make sense. Also, I don't see where you initialize the `yearSalary` variable.

Comment: Chit, you're assigning values to parameters in the constructor -- don't do that. Looking for duplicate to close this with.

Comment: What do you believe the `double salary` parameter to the `Employee` constructors is doing, and why do you believe so? Where do you believe the value of the parameter is stored when the constructor ends, and why do you believe so?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not too difficult to track back to where the 0.00 comes from.

In you for loop in main you use `folks[i].getMonthlyPay()` to get the number to print. So let’s look into the implementations of `getMonthlyPay()`. There are two implementations, one in `SalariedEmployee` and one in `WageEmployee`.

In case of a `SalariedEmployee` the `getMonthlyPay` method uses the value of the field `yearSalary`. Which value is assigned to `yearSalary`? Have you editor or IDE find all the occurrences of `yearSalary` to see where a value is assigned to it. You will see that it happens nowhere. Since `yearSalary` is a field (more precisely, an instance variable), Java assigns 0.00 to it from the start (local varaibles inside a method are different). Since you never assign any other value, the value is still 0.00 when `getMonthlyPay()` divides it by 12 and returns the result. So this is where 0.00 comes from. Can you find a way to fix it?

In case of a `WageEmployee` — you should try the same exercise yourself, find out where the value comes from in `WageEmployee.getMonthlyPay()`. This time you will need to find out both where the value of `wage` and where the value of `hours` come from. Happy searching.